# Elasticsearch - ‘network.host’: is not allowed on ElasticCloud

Tags: elastic-cloud, elasticsearch-watcher

I am using ElasticCloud , version v7.12.1, I have sat up a watcher for health check of cluster that it looks like below:

```
PUT _watcher/watch/cluster_health_watch
    {
      "trigger" : {
        "schedule" : { "cron" : "0 0/5 * * * ?" }
      },
      "input" : {
        "http" : {
          "request" : {
            "host" : "localhost",
            "port" : 9200,
            "path" : "/_cluster/health",
            "auth": {
              "basic": {
                "username": "Myuser",
                "password": "mypassword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "condition" : {
        "compare" : {
          "ctx.payload.status" : { "not_eq" : "green" }
        }
      },
      "actions" : {
      "slackmonitoring" : {
        "throttle_period" : "5m",
        "slack" : {
          "message" : {
            "to" : [ "test-webhook" ], 
            "text" : "Cluster is Unhealthy!" 
          }
        }
      }}
    }
```

It fails with this error:

```
"input": {
      "type": "http",
      "status": "failure",
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "http_host_connect_exception",
            "reason": "Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused"
          }
        ],
```

After doing some search, someone mentioned to add:
network.host: 127.0.0.1 to elasticsearch.yml
However when I add it and try to save it I get this error:

Elasticsearch - 'network.host': is not allowed

I could not find any documentation regarding this issue and a solution for it, I would appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from support, posting the answer in case someone is facing the same issue:

It needs to use elasticsearch public endpoint instead of localhost. So it would look like this:

```
"input" : {
        "http" : {
          "request" : {
            "url" : "https://REDACTED.cloud.es.io:9243/_cluster/health",
            "auth": {
              "basic": {
                "username": "Myuser",
                "password": "mypassword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```